# Vue router push not showing the route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, router

I have a problem with `router.push()`.

It works fine, as long as I come from `“/”`. But when I am on some `“/routeX”` and want to go to `“/routeY”` via `this.$router.push({route: “/routeY” })`, it updates the url in the browser appropriately to *mypage.com/routeY*, but the page is not updated, everything stays the same.

Here is the Vue component via which i do the routing:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { Link } from "@/logic/VueComponentData";
import DetailsPage from "@/views/DetailsPage.vue";
import { PageType } from "@/logic/PageType";

@Component({ components: {} })
export default class RouteRequester extends Vue {
  @Prop() link!: Link;
  @Prop({ default: "white" }) color!: string;
  private go() {
    if (!this.exists()) {
      const config = {
        path: this.link.path[0] == "/" ? this.link.path : "/" + this.link.path,
        component: this.getPageType(),
        name: this.link.path,
        props: { refKey: this.link.href }
      };
      this.$router.addRoute(config);
    }

    this.$router.push({name: this.link.path });
  }

  private exists() {
    const name = this.link.path;
    const link = this.$router.resolve({
      name: name
    });
    if (link && link.href !== "/") {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  private getPageType() {
    switch (this.link.pageType) {
      case PageType.DETAILSPAGE:
        return DetailsPage;
      default:
        throw new Error("not impled");
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Help much appreciated!!!
-bless, Niko

PS: I have posted this to the Vue forum as well. If I find a solution I will update both questions!

Comment: I actually saw your question posted on the Vue Forum a bit ago, and posted this answer, so I will post it here as well.  Since it sounds like you are just changing a param in the route, you probably need to watch for param changes.
See [Reacting to Params Changes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

Comment: Hi Tim, yes thank you!! Here is the link to the vue forum question. 

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-push-not-showing-the-route/111651/3